# (logical) Breadcrumbs for posts. I have the category_id. Is it enough to show the category name?

Tags: php, mysql

For posts pages I have lot of things from the database like post id, titles, contents and the category id.
But I try to create breadcrumb of all posts pages and I cannot show the category name to acheave something like this:

Home -> World -> Something happened somewhere in the world.

"Home" is easy. I can print also the post title with something like this $post['title'] but I really don't have a clue how to put in the breadcrumb the category name. If I have the category_id is there some "magical" way to get the category name. The category names are in another table. Or I have to store the category names in the records for all of the posts.

Thank you!

My tables:

### Categories

```
category_id                   int(11)            
category_name                 varchar(90)                
category_description          text
```

### Posts

```
post_id                    int(11)           
post_title                 varchar(255)                          
post_published_date        datetime CURRENT_TIMESTAMP        
post_content               text                      
category_id                int(11)
```

Comment: Obviously you'll have to get the category name in the category table in your database, but we don't have your structure, so how can we know?

Comment: Ah, this question supposed to be fast and lame. Do I need to include the category name in the same row for the post. But I understand from your comment that there might be way to get the category name from the other table. I thought I can do it myself but.. I will edit my question. :) Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't have to store the category name with each post; you can simply look up the category name in your `Categories` table. I'm a little confused at the question as this seems rather easy...

Say your post information is in `$post`:

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);
$sql = $dbh->prepare(
'SELECT category_name FROM categories WHERE category_id = ?'
);
$sql->execute( array($post['id']) );
$result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($result && isset($result['category_name'])) {
     $category_name = $result['category_name'];
}
else { /* Handle error... */ }
```

If you don't have that many categories and they don't change much, consider storing the category IDs and their corresponding names elsewhere, such that you don't have to query another database each time you serve a post.

Comment: Thank you!!! :) I was actually thinking that there might be some way to get data from DB request that already had the category_id but not the name. :) Yep, it was stupid thinking. The question was pretty simple and easy but anyway.. I did another db request for the name. It works just it has to work. What could be the alternative way for storing the categories names? Some XML/JSON, sessions.. or? I dont get it from first thinking :) Thanx again!

Comment: @MariaZelenova What about a PHP array? A file you could include from anywhere and it just contains a `$category_name` array – done deal! This of course only works if you don't have tons of categories that constantly change. :)

Comment: Yes it is possible too. But this means when I build an admin panel, I will not be able to create/delete categories from it, right?

Comment: @MariaZelenova You could always write a helper script that got all category names and IDs from the database and then saved the resulting array. `var_export()` is a nice function to write a variable to a file.